# Setting up Selenium 4 WebDriver on Eclipse with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, installation, webdriver

I have added Selenium jar files to the build path but still WebDriver keyword is not recognized. I have tried adding the import statement manually. How can I fix this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhYYv.png)

I have added Selenium 4 jars and was expecting that after declaring the WebDriver interface, I would get options to import relevant package but did not. I typed in the import statement manually but still the issue was not solved.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your _Default_ package? If yes, delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).

Comment: Remove all the "-sources" files.  Those will cause namespace conflicts.